# Conversion of plain text file to html file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to convert a .txt file say abc.txt into html file and attach this html file to the mail which is getting triggered by my script.

I want to preserve the format of .txt file which is a plain text with new lines and special characters like -,:;/()

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: Hmm. Welcome to stack overflow, Please ask an [\[  mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have told us what you want to do but you have not told us why you can't do it. You need to try it yourself, show your code and ask a specific question. We won't just write the code for you and we can't help you unless you tell us what *specifically* you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<pre>` of html:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
plain text sith spaces and newlines
</pre>
</html>
```

This should be fine as an attachment. When you put this in the body of your message, some mail clients will show it with a proportional font, and nice formatted columns (with spaces) get terrible.
There is a solution for that, but that is a different question.